# Using microprocessor over microcontroller in ECU?

Tags: microcontroller, automotive, microprocessor

What are the benefits/advantages of using microprocessor than microcontroller in ECU(which are used in automotive applications)

Comment: First you should define what is the difference of a microprocessor vs microcontroller. To me, the definition is that a microcontroller is a chip with microprocessor, memories and peripherals integrated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a Microprocessor, can be way more powerful, but way more complex to implement and require much more work than an MCU.

An MCU is basically a computer on its own that contains a microprocessor, ram and flash, while a microprocessor will not.

Beyond the clock speed, microprocessor often have more advanced instruction handling, a larger instruction set, higher cache memory, making them better performers.

Our days sees more and more powerful MCU, some of which can even run at few hundred Mhz, and run OS like Linux, although it does not compare to processors that runs in the Ghz range.

The main component is the instruction speed, measured in IPS (instruction per second) or sometimes in [DMIPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhrystone).

A high-end ARM based MCU like STM32F7x6 is capable of 462 DMIPS at 216Mhz, while an intel I7 handle 56'000 DMIPS at 3Ghz so effectively 120x faster.

Beside the raw processing speed, it means also how fast an algorithm can be executed.

In terms of automotive, the importance of speed is for the control of ABS, Airbags and so forth, as the system latency is of outmost importance, as ms/us response time, translate to meters traveled in a vehicle at high speed.

At 120km/h a vehicle travels 33m/s, if the ABS algorithm takes 1ms to execute, that is 33cm traveled, if it takes 120ms it's 4 meters.

There of, the algorithm to deploy airbags, trigger ABS, or other safety systems needs to run as fast as possible, and may be the difference between life and death.

Comment: Can you give an example how the microprocessor is way more powerful than an MCU in automotive application perspective?

Comment: In short they are available with higher clock speeds - microprocessors can clock in the GHz range while microcontrollers currently clock in the 16-240MHz range.  While microprocessors typically have support for large external flash and RAM, microcontrollers typically use relatively limited internal storage.  That said, the demarcation between the two is increasingly blurred these days, with microcontrollers having external memory bus interfaces.  So from an automotive perspective the additional storage and potentially shorter interrupt latency of a microprocessor may be beneficial.

Comment: I added more details @Elchupacabra

Comment: The response time of safety features in a car will likely mostly depend on CAN bus protocol design. You'll have a real-time bus cycle of 1m or 10ms. How fast it stops depends on the real-time spec, not on some variable execution speed of individual CPUs. They will need to have data ready within their specified real-time. And mostly cars use a de-centralized design so you don't (shouldn't) have a whole lot of calculations in one place. The ABS will have its own MCU and so on.

Comment: Modern cars use safety MCUs for this purpose. Typically Cortex M or low-end Power PC. You won't find any x86 etc there.

Comment: @Elchupacabra What makes you think a "microprocessor" has ever been used in a car? Can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the required code and data memory are on chip for a given microcontroller, this has the advantage of there not being high speed data and address bus wiring in the ‘real world’. The advantage here is less potential for EMC issues with high speed signals radiating and also being susceptible to transients. Nevertheless, many ECUs in the 80’s and 90’s had external eprom and flash chips.

Having everything on chip means less solder joints etc as points of failure. Other considerations might be security as in unauthorized people not being able to access, copy or change the code.